# Get the cell name of a WebSphere app Server

Tags: java, websphere

> Is there a way to get the cell name of my WebSphere application server
>   through java?

**I tried using this code but I'm getting a null pointer exception.**

```
AdminService adminService = AdminServiceFactory.getAdminService(); System.out.println(adminService.getCellName());
```

Comment: Are you running this code on a WebContainer?

Comment: I'm running this code in a standalone java application. I imported the jars from WebSphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to DMGR or WAS standalone from your external java application by using JMX connection (SOAP/RMI)

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tjmx_develop.html